# Remove characters after word, javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the characters after a certain word in a string.

`www.google.com/Server/someOtherStuffIDontWant`

So far I have come up with this:

`str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("Server/")) + "Server/";`

Is that the best approach?

Comment: How do you define 'best'?

Comment: @Oriol idk, whatever the stardard is?

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut Any reason you felt compelled to roll back the edit? I won't re-edit the question, but FYI - [thanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and [tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles/130208#130208) are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like regex's for this task (but this a very opion-oriented answer, to be honest):

```
str = str.replace(/Server\/.*/, 'Server')
```

Comment: ah, I really like the `str.split('Server/')[0]` answer.  I think that's my new fav :)

To answer this in a much broader sense, though, the best approach is one that is test-able and one that gets the job done in the amount of time you have based on your business constraints.  Don't get fooled into thinking that there is usually a `best` way to do things... it's all relative to the task at hand and how much time you have to do it.  Cheers!

Comment: I removed my answer because his was so simple.

Comment: @Script47 Not to be rude but yours was wrong

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut that's not being rude, for future references where did I go wrong? The fiddle seemed to work?

Comment: @Script47 your answer erased the "Server" part

Comment: @NorCalKnockOut ah thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way and *If... only if*
you want to get **all before the last apperance of the `/` character**:

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

> "www.google.com/Server"

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

> "www.google.com/Server/"

means that if you have an URL like:

```
www.google.com/Server/Home/User/someOtherStuffIDontWant
```

> "www.google.com/Server/Home/User"

Answer (score 0):

this will extract what you want.

```
str.match(/.*\/Server/)[0];
```

it matches any number of any characters following by `/server`. 
`str.match()`captures the array of matched sequences. In your case it is just the 1st one you want.

Answer (score -1):

That's one way. If you're going the substring route, you can just get the exact substring you want in one shot, like so:

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("Server/") + 7);
```

Or, more generally:

```
var searchTerm = "Server/";

str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(searchTerm) + searchTerm.length);
```

or you might go with a regular expression:

```
str = str.replace(/Server\/.*$/, "Server/");
```

Comment: and we're downvoting because...?